# Password Validation Pattern in angular 2

Tags: angular, forms, validation

I have tried this code for **password pattern** validation but it not works, tell me how to validate the pattern

HTML code:-

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm"  (ngSubmit)="submit()" >
<ion-item>
    <ion-label primary floating>PASSWORD</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="password" id="password"  class="form-control" formControlName="password" minlength="4" maxlength="20" required></ion-input>
</ion-item>
    <p *ngIf="myForm.controls.password.errors && myForm.controls.password.dirty ">
       <small class="up"><strong><i>Password Must Contain(4-20) 1-char! 1-number!</i></strong></small></p>
</form>
```

ts file:-

```
export class SinupPage {

myForm: FormGroup
passwordRegex: any = '((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{4,20})' ;

this.myForm = formBuilder.group({
        'password'       : new FormControl('',Validators.compose([Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4), Validators.maxLength(20),Validators.pattern(this.passwordRegex]))
  }
 submit(){
 let registerNewUserObj ={
        password:this.myForm.value.password   
  }
```

When I enter data into the field, getting error *Password Must Contain(4-20) 1-char! 1-number!* which is

tag, but i need to validate the password like thi must contains 1 char 1 number,

Only entering Chars or Only entering number, the error message is displaying

Answer (score 3):

Regex should be like this

> /^(?=.*[A-Za-z])(?=.*\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,20}/

`(?=.*[A-Za-z])` - Assert a string has at least one Alphabet;

`(?=.*\d)` -Assert a string has at least one number;

`[A-Za-z\d]{4,20}` - Characters (Only numbers and letters) length should be between 4 and 20

Comment: whether i could write in input field or ts file

Comment: If you want to use it in input, put pattern="/^(?=.[A-Za-z])(?=.\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,20}$/". If you want to use inside ts, use as mentioned as above

Comment: I used in the ts file like this

Comment: Is it throwing any error or is it not working as expected? try using in input?

Answer (score 0):

call it like this: `Validators.pattern(/^(?=.[A-Za-z])(?=.\d)[A-Za-z\d]{4,20}/)`